# How to run parallel controller with csv data in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, sftp

I have a jmeter test plan file with following structure
[image]

My aim is to do SFTP get with different username and password that run in parallel using parallel controller. The username and password are stored in a CSV.

[image]

How to achieve this? as far as I know the parallel controller won't loop a csv sequentially like a common thread group so I can't store the username and password into variable then use it in my parallel controller. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why you would need the Parallel Controller, if you want to execute SFTP requests concurrently just add more threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

If you want to run single request by multiple users at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)